# Django display posts on index page with few answers (linked by foreign key) under each one of them

Tags: python, django, model

I am writing an Imageboard in Django but I can't get over this basic issue how to display few answers to each post on the mainpage. I have two models, Thread and Answer, and answer is linked by foreign key to thread. I would like to display each Thread with three latest answers underneath. I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your models.py is like this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    # you can add other fields


class Answer(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thread_ans')
    answer = models.TextField()
    if_correct = models.BooleanField()
    # you can add other fields
```

**views.py**

```
def quest(request):
    q1 = Answer.objects.filter(if_correct=True).select_related('thread')  # if you want only correct answer in template
    q2 = Thread.objects.all().prefetch_related('thread_ans')  # For all answers

    conext = {
        'q1': q1,
        'q2': q2,
    }
```

**in template**

```
# <!---- For Question and correct  answer ------>
{% for i in q1 %}
<p>Ques: i.thread.question</p>
<p>Ans: i.answer</p>
{% endfor %}

# <!---- For Question and all answers with correct or incorrect ------>
{% for i in q2 %}
<p>Ques: i.question</p>
{% for j in i.thread_ans.all %}
<p>j.answer</p> # <!-- Print answer --->
<p>j.is_correct</p> # <!-- Print if correct or not --->
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter tags to show 3 comments , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/ 
You can find latest 3 answers for each thread inside custom filter tag like this .

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(Thread = Thread).order_by('date')[0:3]
```

Comment: How would I get the correct answers for each thread in template then? Do I understand correctly that I am supposed to send answers variable as a context in view?